# getting NaN when trying to cast string to int

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting some very weird results here. I'm trying to convert a string into a integer. Consider the following code below.

```
           //Send back to client.
            io.emit('returned message', {
                'message': message,
                'chatid': chatid,
                'userid': userid
            });
            console.log("Returning the data to chat " + chatid);
```

Which is sending data back to client, the console log looks like this:

> Returning the data to the chat '5'

and in the client I have

```
alert(typeof msg.chatid);
alert(msg.chatid)
var test = Number(msg.chatid);
alert(typeof test)
alert(test);
```

Which produces the following results

> String and '5'
>   Number and NaN

**Please note I've tried Number() and parseInt()**

However, trying to code in Jsfiddle, it works fine. I have no idea why I'm getting NaN. Any ideas?

```js
var num = '5';

alert(Number(num));
```

Comment: Try outputting `msg.chatid.length` and `msg.chatid.charCodeAt(0)`

Comment: I have a feeling the actual contents of chatid are `'5'` rather than `5`, which is why it can't be parsed into a number. Otherwise I see no reason why you would get those quotation marks on your console.log. *Edit*: Confirmed it with next comment, char code of `'` is 39.

Comment: @4castle `msg.chatid.length` returned 3 and `msg.chatid.charCodeAt(0)` returned 39

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I'm using Socket.io to send data from server to client. I use console.log on both the client and server and both results return '5'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have single quotationmarks around your "int" value.

> Returning the data to the chat '5'

Looks like it's escaped before your socket transmission?

Comment: You're right! It was already escaped...good catch! I'll set you as answered in 2 minutes when I'm allowed to. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. And in future: if it says it is NaN, it is NaN ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the + to quick convert to Number and provide fallback

```js
var getNum = (n) => (+n) ? +n : -1

var chatid = '5'
var chatidinvalid = '5test'
var chatidnan = NaN

console.log("Returning the data to chat ", getNum(chatid));
console.log("Returning the data to chatidinvalid: ", getNum(chatidinvalid));
console.log("Returning the data to chatidinvalid: ", getNum(chatidnan));
```

Answer (score -4):

try using `parseInt()`.

```js
var num = '5';

alert(parseInt(num));
```

Comment: If you read my entire post you will see I have already tried that. Its even bolded.

Comment: Are you sure that chatid's value is always a number string?